# How to get the cookies from a php into a variable with post data

Tags: php, variables, cookies, http-post

How to get the cookies from a php into a variable with post data? I'm stuck, please help!

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want cookies, they're stored in the global array `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']`. If you want to store one you must call `setcookie('name','value',$expiry_time)`.